# does dom element visibility matters to javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know `id` has to be unique for the current dom, but does that hold even if the 2 dom elements will never be visible at the same time.

I have this scenario:

```
<div class="visible-lg visible-md">
  <div id="test"></div>
</div>
.
.
.
<div class="visible-sm visible-xs">
 <div id="test"></div>
</div>

<script>
  .
  .
  .
   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "this text";
</script>
```

No matter what device size I'm in, only the first element get updated. How can I ensure right element gets updated?

Answer (score 1):

> I know id has to be unique for the current dom, but does that hold even if the 2 dom elements will never be visible at the same time.

Yes. Visibility is irrelevant, `id`s must be unique. It's not a JavaScript thing, it's [a DOM thing](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-id) [the layer under HTML]:

> An element can have an associated unique identifier (ID)

Note the term "unique."

Answer (score 0):

If you manage to delete the Dom that you are hiding and append it when needed (delete older one then) , and then you can have same ID for both, because at one time you will have only one element with that Id.